# Puzzling variable expansion behavior when calling zsh from a Ruby script

Tags: ruby, zsh

I have a Ruby script that runs a zsh command. Variable assignment in a zsh for-loop just doesn't work when I call it from Ruby.

```
# This just prints three newlines from the three echo invocations
# x does not get assigned to anything
puts `zsh -c "for x in 1 2 3; do echo $x; done"`
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the shell expand `$x` with value of the shell variable `$x`.

```
>> puts `x=9999; zsh -c "for x in 1 2 3; do echo $x; done"`
9999
9999
9999
```

You can prevent of it using single quote:

```
puts `zsh -c 'for x in 1 2 3; do echo $x; done'`
```

or by escape `$`:

```
puts `zsh -c "for x in 1 2 3; do echo \\$x; done"`
```